# update Interaction Model without resubmission

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

My intention is my users can insert some intent to my alexa skill using my applications. So I need to change the intent schema and sample utterance of my alexa skill dynamically.

Is there any way to update intent schema and sample utterances without resubmisson and without using amazon developer portal.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no way to update the configuration of a skill programmatically or dynamically.

There is a popular feature request in for this though:. 
https://forums.developer.amazon.com/content/idea/49556/programmatic-way-to-update-slots-intent-schema-and.html

Comment: Sorry to hear it. Thanks for feedback.