# Amazon Alexa API

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

I want to create a BackOffice where I can create questions (utterances) and answers (database table's content) on just one intent - on one custom skill.

I'll be using outsystems so I can't use node.js or java.
So I need to use a REST METHOD (API) -> I need to update the interaction model of one custom skill via REST. And I have no ideia how it's done.

BackOffice: Where the user can add questions and match it with the answers. Basically it's manipulating the Alexa for whatever question(s) we want to give the answers we want. When the admin/user adds a question to the database I need it to be updated do my interaction model (Utterances of my Intent of my Custom Skill)

The goal is to have a ChatBot, where you ask predefined questions and Alexa answers predefined answers.

Any tips?

Thank you so much,
Diogo Mendes

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your need correctly, you should take a look at the Alexa Skills Kit Skill Management API (SMAPI). With that, you can update your interaction model by making a request to the API. [The documentation](https://developer.amazon.com/de/docs/smapi/interaction-model-operations.html) shows you how to do that. However, this has a major downside. Changes to your interaction model will have to go through the certification process. (see [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41805642/update-interaction-model-without-resubmission?rq=1))

Comment: I've been trying to use SMAPI (CLI) without success. I create a lambda fuction but then Alexa Skills Kit doesnt "integrate" with API Gateway, so when I open outsystems (yes i'm using outsystems) and try to call a REST method, I can call the skills kit separately but i cant call the api with it.

I'ts been a hell of a problem, I don't know what should I do more...

So if I want to update utterances the only way is to introduce them manually? (alexa dev console & ask cli ??)

Comment: I can't totally follow what you're saying. Your actual skill, which runs as a lambda function is different from the Skills Management API. But you should be able to call SMAPI from within Lambda. So your Lambda function (your custom skill) should handle requests and based on them call the SM-API to adjust your interaction model. Is that what you're trying?

Comment: nevertheless i am trying another path but without success either..

so new plan: 1) i want to create a custom skill, then add only one intent called "QuestionIntent"´
2) then add a lot of utterances that are "the" questions.
3) Then I want Alexa to respond those questions, but the answers are manipulated by me, example: "Are you ready? The answer must be: "yes I am sir".
But when i test it on the alexa console it says "im unable to reach the requested skill". I'm lost.. and getting out of time.. I know i'm bothering you but you are really my last chance..